# Element must be user-editable in order to clear it when try to enter date into date field

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm trying to send date into date field with below statement. After running the script, getting below error message. Could you please help me out?

HTML:

```
<div class="forms-group-inline calendar-initialized" data-dateinputmanager-cutoffdate="2016-09-06" data-agent="DateInputManager"> 
    <label class="col-6 forms-textinput date-input forms-compact "> 
        <span class="forms-labeltext">Leave</span> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" value="2/24/16" name="ar.rt.leaveSlice.date"/> 
        <div class="forms-input-actions"> 
            <div class="forms-input-actions-wrapper"> 
                <a class="h1 forms-input-action" title="Leave" href="#"> 
                    <span class="offscreen">Leave</span> 
                    <span class="i i-calendar"/>
```

Code trial:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='h1 forms-input-action' and @title='Leave']")).sendKeys("1/22/16");
```

I have tried the below code as well but getting same error:

```
WebElement BirthDate= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='h1 forms-input-action' and @title='Leave']")); 
BirthDate.clear(); BirthDate.sendKeys("1/20/16");
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.
Command duration or timeout: 23.02 seconds
```

Comment: first click on it, than clear and finally use send keys....with valid xpath

Answer (score 0):

As per provided HTML code, the xpath you used //a[@class='h1 forms-input-action' and @title='Leave'] is for link (as tag is 'a'). So you can't do sendkeys as it is not input field.

```
<a class="h1 forms-input-action" title="Leave" href="#">
```

Please inspect input field with firebug/fire path or by selenium IDE and use that locator.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Thank you murali !.. could you please help me then how to select date?                                                         <div class="forms-input-actions">
<div class="forms-input-actions-wrapper">
<a class="h1 forms-input-action" title="Leave" href="#">
<span class="offscreen">Leave</span>
<span class="i i-calendar"/>

Comment: need to find the location of input field. please inspect with firebug and provide html code of input box. so that i can help you with xpath or any other locators.

Comment: xpath of the element is //a[@class='h1 forms-input-action' and @title='Leave']". html code is                                                                                   <label class="col-6 forms-textinput date-input forms-compact ">
<span class="forms-labeltext">Leave</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" value="2/24/16" name="ar.rt.leaveSlice.date"/>
<div class="forms-input-actions">
<div class="forms-input-actions-wrapper">
<a class="h1 forms-input-action" title="Leave" href="#">
<span class="offscreen">Leave</span>
<span class="i i-calendar"/>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</label>

Comment: hey, this is total DOM HTML code, by seeing it and telling input box location is difficult. just inspect with firebug, it will highlight the HTML code of input box.

Answer (score 0):

### HTML `<a>` Tag

The `<a>` tag defines a hyperlink, which is used to link from one page to another. So you can't invoke `sendKeys()` on ***A*** tags.

Instead you need to invoke *`clear()`* and/or *`sendKeys()`* on the *`<input>`* tag as follows:

```
WebElement BirthDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='forms-labeltext' and text()='Leave']//following::input[1]"));
BirthDate.clear();
BirthDate.sendKeys("1/22/16")
```